# problem when parsing JSON with Go JSONPath

Tags: json, go, jsonpath

I used the code to convert json data from Yarn REST API to Prometheus data type:
https://github.com/prometheus-community/json_exporter.
However, it printed errors:

> level=error ts=2021-07-08T06:31:03.712Z caller=collector.go:83 msg="Failed to extract value for metric" path={.capacity} err="capacity is not found" metric="Desc{fqName: "queues_capacity", help: "information on queues", constLabels: {}, variableLabels: [type]}"

I was wondering if there is some wrong in my configuration of YAML file (such as in terms of nested json) or just the reason about the code.

my yaml config is:

```
metrics:
- name: queues
  path: "{ .scheduler.schedulerInfo.queues.queue }"
  help: information on queues
  type: object
  labels:
       type: '{.type}'
  values:
       capacity: '{.capacity}'
```

and part of the json file is:

```
{
"scheduler": {
"schedulerInfo": {
"type": "capacityScheduler",
"capacity": 100,
"usedCapacity": 1.0526316,
"maxCapacity": 100,
"queueName": "root",
"queues": {
"queue": [
{
"type": "capacitySchedulerLeafQueueInfo",
"capacity": 10,
"usedCapacity": 10.526316,
"maxCapacity": 100,
```

Comment: could it be possible that the field key capacity in the response json is not consistent, as in some cases it is not returned in the json object at all?

Comment: I have checked it, there are five queues object in total, and every one has the capacity field

Answer (score 0):

use [*] to get all object first, so it should be:

```
  path: "{ .scheduler.schedulerInfo.queues.queue[*] }"
```

according to this: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/